# The Arctic Rainforest

Tags: climate

In one of my alternate Earths, I have created a climate so warm that the dominant feature of the Arctic isn't ice, but forests.  They consist of the following trees:
Pine
Oak
Araucaria
Sequoia
Fir
Douglas fir
Cedar
Spruce
Yew
Maple
Cottonwood
Alder
Rowan
Birch
Beech
Aspen
Elm
Hazel
Apple
Pear
Plum
Peach
Apricot
Ginkgo

Using these trees as clues, what kind of climate have I created?

Comment: That's a big range of trees. For example: peach needs a relatively hot climate while apple would grow in higher latitudes. You should narrow the list and use some punctuation.

Comment: These are trees that can survive frost.

Comment: I remembered researching what kinds of fruit can survive frost, and peach is listed among them.

Comment: @Vincent: I beg to differ about growing peaches in Canada.  Along with cherries, grapes, and other fruit, they're a major crop in the Okanogan Valley (BC).  There's even a town called Peachland, a bit south of Kelowna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer, but a few comments on forestry which suggests that there really isn't an answer.

Pretty much all of those will grow, if cultivated, within 25 miles or so of my home on the east slope of the Sierra Nevada.  (Fairly near Reno.)  I have about 15 of the 25 or so growing on my property.

That said, you aren't going to find all of them growing in company, as they require specific conditions.  Aspens, for instance, like the wet soil along streams & meadows in the mountains, while Sequoias are found in the dry summer/snowy winter climate on the west side of the Sierra.  Cottonwoods like river bottoms...

Then notice that almost all forests in the western US between the Sierra and the Rockies are conifers, with large deciduous trees being rare.  East of the Mississippi the situation is reversed, with deciduous being more plentiful than conifers.  They just like different growning conditions.

So if your forested Arctic area is continent-sized, you can have enough variation in rainfall &c to have all those grow somewhere, but likely not together.  And you have a temperate climate, much like what you'd have if you took a slice through the US at about 40 degrees latitude.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not to be a killjoy, but the dominant feature of the new Arctic will be water. A warmer climate will melt the polar ice caps and raise the level of the ocean by about 200 feet. The Arctic will be mostly underwater - that is, even more than it is now. As it stands, Arctic land consists of Alaska (United States), Canada, Finland, Greenland (Denmark), Iceland, Norway, Russia, and Sweden. For all but Canada (the Arctic Archipelago) and Greenland, the area north of the Arctic Circle is a fairly narrow strip of land bordering the Arctic Ocean.

If you want to set your story at the *South* Pole (Antarctica), that's a different story, but not a great one. The variations in terrain elevation found in Antarctica would be important in providing the different climates required by the different species, but with the problem that the high altitude of the interior makes it a desert. Again, you'd only get forests around the edges of the zone, but for different reasons (not enough water, rather than too much).

However, in either case the long summer days and long winter nights will continue to produce major temperature swings, it's just that the average temperatures will be higher. This will cause considerable climatic challenges for your forest species. In the Arctic, because of the moderating effect of the Arctic Sea, where the water temperature doesn't fall much below freezing, land temperature swings run about 140 F (-60 to +80), so raising the winter temperature by (let's say) 40 F will raise summer temperatures to 120, and that will have severe effects on most of the species you've listed. Sequoias, for instance, are quite intolerant of hot humid summers - and that means New England summers, not the Deep South.

Virtually none of the species you've mentioned is adapted to polar light cycles, so you're going to have to invoke some serious genetic engineering.

Comment: Palm trees were found in Greenland, and it was close to where it is now during the Eocene.  Let me worry about the sea levels.